# JavaScript--indexOf Basics

Tags: javascript

In the following snippet, what role does `pos = string.indexOf( 'e', pos + 1 )` play?

```
var string = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question';

var count = 0;

var pos = string.indexOf('e');

while ( pos !== -1 ) {
  count++;
  pos = string.indexOf( 'e', pos + 1 )
}

console.log(count);
```

Comment: It searches the string for the *next* occurrence of `e`, beginning the search with the character following the last `e` that was found to avoid finding and counting any of them multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), `indexOf` takes an additional parameter:

> *fromIndex* (Optional)
>
> The index at which to start the searching forwards in the string. It can be any integer. The default value is 0, so the whole array is searched. If *fromIndex < 0* the entire string is searched. If *fromIndex >= str.length*, the string is not searched and -1 is returned. Unless *searchValue* is an empty string, then *str.length* is returned.

Judging purely from this information, the behaviour of the program as a whole is easily deduced:

- It counts the number of times `e` appears in the string overall, using `string.indexOf` to find each occurence.

`string.indexOf` only returns the position of the *first* occurence of the character in the string. By passing and updating `fromIndex` with the value of `pos`, `string.indexOf` finds all subsequent occurences of `e` by ignoring characters before `pos`.

A counter is updated each time it does so, allowing the program as a whole to compute the number of times `e` appears in the string.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of the `indexOf` function is the index you want to start to look in the string

As you can see in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

If you didn't use the secondParam in that case, you would be getting the position of the first '**e**' forever.
This function is counting the numbers of '**e**'s in that phrase.

Comment: Does `pos` inside the `while` statement override the `pos` outside the statement?

Comment: You could say that, but that's not exactly an `overwrite`. You are just assigning a new value for that variable.

Comment: And that value only takes effect *inside* the scope of the `while` statement, correct?

Comment: Not at all, the same way you're changing the value of count (incrementing it), you're assigning a new value to `pos` too. You can try it adding `pos` in the console.log

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in string.indexOf is the index of the string to start searching from.

See here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#Parameters

All this code does is count the number of e's in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> The `indexOf()` method returns the position of the first occurrence of
>   a specified value in a string.

**Syntax :**

```
string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)
```

- **searchvalue** - [*Required*]. The string to search for
- **start** - [*Optional*]. Default 0. At which position to start the search

Return a Number, representing the position where the specified `searchvalue` occurs for the first time, or -1 if it never occurs

```
var str = "To be, or not to be, that is the question";
var n = str.indexOf("e", 5);
```

The above code returns the first occurrence of the letter "e" in a string, starting the search at position 5:

For more : [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

**Note**: The `indexOf()` method is case sensitive.